# Random Sorting MySQL - Same order if element is altered/removed?

Tags: mysql, database, sorting, random

Say I have the following table

```
Table1

item, value
----------------------
1        1      
2        2       
3        1       
4        1       
5        1
```

Let's say that sorting by value DESC then by rand() would result in 2,4,3,5,1 as the order

If the value of item 3 was then changed to 3

```
Table1

item, value
----------------------
1        1      
2        2       
3        3       
4        1       
5        1
```

Then the sort order would change to something like 3,2,5,1,4.

So my question: is there anyway for the sort order to persist and for only the changed object to move up the list?  So my expected result for the first list would be 2,4,3,5,1 and for the second it would be 3,2,4,5,1.  So the 3 simply moves up the list without changing the position of the other randomly ordered elements.  I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can try using `rand(number)` where the number is a seed number (any number you like)
so something like

```
SELECT item FROM table1 ORDER BY value desc, rand(1)
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/587c2/1) In the fiddle, table1 and table2 are exactly the same except for value of item 3, see how `rand()` with a seed works.

Comment: This works if the element is moved, but is there anyway to do this if the element is deleted?  [sqlFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc960/1)

Comment: There is a way, by not deleting item but marking it as deleted with another column then do an outer select for where deleted = 0 like this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01773/3)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can add one more column to your table. If you can then,
add one column to table which automatically gets updated with current timestamp whenever a record is updated. And then you can sort by that timestamp field and then by rand.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
ADD COLUMN update_time TIMESTAMP 
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

and then you can order like:  `ORDER BY update_time, rand();`

Comment: Why would sorting by the time a record is updated help?  I'm trying to achieve random sorting.